# Multiply length using \expr

Tags: calculations, arithmetic

I have a length that I wish to scale, however I am not sure of how to do it, and none of the answers i have found online have been helpful.

The function I attempted to derive this from is:

```
% #1 is the unit to convert to
% #2 is the length to convert
\makeatletter
\def\convertto#1#2{\strip@pt\dimexpr #2*65536/\number\dimexpr 1#1}
\makeatother
```

into:

```
% #1 is the length
% #2 is the multiple
% #3 is the output units
\makeatletter
\def\multlen#1#2#3{\strip@pt\dimexpr #1*65536*\numexpr #2/\number\dimexpr 1#3}
\makeatother
```

An example of use as follows:

```
\begin{document}
\multlen{.5in}{2}{in}
... other content
\end{document}
```

Some desired outputs are as follows:

> `\multlen{.5in}{2}{in}`  to return 1in
>
> `\multlen{1in}{2}{in}`  to return 2in
>
> `\multlen{.5in}{5}{in}`  to return 2.5in

The result is *Aritmetic overflow*.

Comment: your question isn't very clear, `2\textwidth` is twice `\textwidth` and `2\dimexpr 5in\relax` is 10in. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: to express a length in units you can use `\dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn`  eg `\dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn{2\textwidth}{1cm}` would give the value  cm

Comment: I was trying to show how the length could vary, but so could the multiple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeX lengths do not record any unit so for calculation a "return unit" is not useful and you can multiply a length just by prefixing it with a factor, so `2\textwidth` is twice `\textwidth` and `2\dimexpr 5in\relax` is 10in.

For debugging and documentation purposes, rescaling to show a length in a specfic unit can be useful, and latex provides `\dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\lengthunit[2]{\dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn{#1}{1#2}#2}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\lengthunit{\textwidth}{cm}

\lengthunit{2\textwidth}{cm}

\lengthunit{1in}{cm}

\lengthunit{5\dimexpr 1in\relax}{cm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No mention of dimeval?

Comment: @likethevegetable I could add "`\dimeval` is not used here" as a mention?